# Format of an HTTP get request

Tags: http, get, http-headers

I'm writing an HTTP server (for the sole purpose of educating myself).

A typical GET request seems to be this:

```
GET /?a=1&b=2 HTTP/1.1 
Host: localhost    
User-Agent: my browser details
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8    
Accept-Language: en-gb,en;q=0.5    
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate    
Connection: keep-alive
```

The only place I can see the variables being sent is in the first line.
It would be easy enough to write a regex to get the variables and their contents, but I'm wondering if there is an easier way. I ask because I always assumed that the idea of `url?first_variable=first_value&second_variable=second_value` was part of the protocol, and special in some way. However, as far as I can see, this isn't the case, and I could equally just do `url$first_variable-first_value?second_variable-second_value` or something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are referring to is the Query portion of a URL, as defined in [section 3.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4) of the [URL specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986), and allowed by [section 3.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.2) of the [HTTP specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616).

Passing parameters in the requested URL is not the only way to send parameters in an HTTP request, though.  Another option is to use the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` Content Type in a `POST` request, as defined by [section 17.13.4](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4) of the HTML 4.01 specification and [section 4.10.22](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/forms.html#form-submission-0) of the HTML5 specification, eg:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1 
Host: localhost    
User-Agent: my browser details
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8    
Accept-Language: en-gb,en;q=0.5    
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate    
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 7

a=1&b=2
```

```
POST / HTTP/1.1 
Host: localhost    
User-Agent: my browser details
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8    
Accept-Language: en-gb,en;q=0.5    
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate    
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=myboundary

--myboundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="a"

1
--myboundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="b"

2
--myboundary--
```

Comment: So just to clarify, there _isn't_ any technical meaning behind the use of `?`, `=` and `&`, but they are in the URL specification, which is why they are the standard?

Comment: Read the standards, they do have meaning. A query string is part of the URL and does help uniquely identify a specific resource. HTTP does not care if a URL query string is present, it is treated as part of the URL and it is the entire URL that identifies the resource. However, moving the parameters out of the URL query string and into the `POST` body does change the URL, so placement is important. Whether a URL requires a query string or not depends on the type of resource being exposed to clients. It is possible to use both a URL query string and POST body parameters in the same request.

Comment: Is it possible to pass parameters in the Body of HTTP get request?

Comment: Nope. If you do, it will be ignored.

Comment: you can also send variables in custom headers but that would be part of application specific logic ... one example might be a custom auth header for providing extending user info